# Cron Job Failure on GAE with java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I am working on project using GWT java GAE. In my project i have used cron job. 
when i schedule its time like every 5 minutes, every 2 minutes in `cron.xml` then its working fine i will getting my ouput. but when i schedule it time like every `24 hours` or every day `21:00` then cron job executed but its throw error :-

```
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.825
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Date Before Adding  Day03-Nov-2015
    E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.832
  com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Today Date -30 Days DateSat Oct 03 23:59:59 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.832
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Today DateMon Nov 02 18:30:00 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.832
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Date After Setting the Time Mon Nov 02 23:59:59 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Date Before Adding  Day03-Nov-2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Today Date +30 Days DateWed Dec 02 18:30:00 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Date Before Adding One DayMon Nov 02 18:30:00 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Today Date +30 Days DateThu Dec 03 18:29:29 UTC 2015
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: In Contract List
E 2015-11-03 20:18:10.833
com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl ContractRenewallist: Date After Adding One DateMon Nov 02 23:59:59 UTC 2015
I 2015-11-03 20:18:11.146
```

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see associated `DeadlineExceededException` errors in the logs for those requests?

Comment: thanks for your response but its not throwing DeadlineExceededException

Comment: its throwing :-  This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Answer (score 1):

The message about starting a new instance is not an error, it's just an informational message, expected when app instances are dynamically created (note the `i` marking):

[image]

GAE automatically stops dynamic instances after a period of inactivity (of at least 15 minutes) and start new instances on demand. Your app instance is not idle long enough when the job is scheduled every 2 or 5 minutes because of the cron job itself, but it may be when running the job daily.

More details in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class).

You can see the message even when running the job every 2 or 5 minutes if, for example, you stop your instance manually.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response My cron job executed once a day at night so that time my app instance is idle so how can i execute Cron Job at night

Comment: You're already executing it at night. All is fine, you can ignore the informational message.

Comment: Thanks a lot but its not giving the output. means cron job executing at time but its servlet class executing only 4, 5 lines. why its not executing total servlet class.

Comment: When i schedule cron job every 2 minutes or every 5 minutes and my app is not in idle then the cron job executing the servlet total class and its giving me the output.     But when i schedule once a day then its only executing 3 4 lines of cron job servlet implementation class. Why its happening this? could you please help me  Dan Cornilescu Thanks in advance